# How to get text from a Word document into another Word Document

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have two Word documents that both contain one word in each document.
I have third document that needs to pull each word from the two documents and edit all hyperlinks in the document using the replace function.
The replace function works if I enter a string into the function but does not work if when trying to pull the two words from the documents

```
Public Sub Document_Open()
    Dim x As Document

    Set newSource = Application.Documents.Open("\\t1dc\Everyone\Ben\ns.docx", ReadOnly:=True, Visible:=False)
    Set oldSource = Application.Documents.Open("\\t1dc\Everyone\Ben\os.docx", ReadOnly:=True, Visible:=False)

    Dim newServer As Range
    Set newServer = newSource.Content

    'Test using message box
    MsgBox newServer

    Dim oldServer As Range
    Set oldServer = oldSource.Content

    'Test using message box
    MsgBox oldServer

    For Each h In ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks
           h.Address = Replace(h.Address, oldServer.Text, newServer.Text)
           MsgBox h.Address
    Next

    newSource.Close
    oldSource.Close

    Set x = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't see a "Replace function" in the question. You need to include *all* relevant information (a [mcve]) so that people can reproduce the circumstances. Also describe what is meant by "it doesn't work" - that's not an accurate problem description. Best guess: `ActiveDocument` isn't the file you think it is. Create an object for that document, as well, and assign it *before* opening other documents.

Comment: Sorry first time poster. The replace function is called in the For Each loop. If I use a message box to display the variables oldServer and newServer, it displays the text that is contained in the document which im pulling from. However, the replace function does not seem to be able to read the variables oldServer or newServer. But If I enter a string, example "server1" into the replace function parameters, the function works correctly and does the string replacements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the length of oldServer and newServer, because you're also pulling in the `\r` that is at the end of a line.

Answer (score 0):

Yes thank you!

Removed from end of string and it works

Dim oldS As String
oldS = Left(oldServer.Text, Len(oldServer.Text) - 1)